# Starting fancyhdr from title page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, apa-style

I am creating a latex document with the following format:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace,caption}
\captionsetup{font=doublespacing}% Double-spaced float captions
\doublespacing% Double-spaced document text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\lhead{MY RUNNING HEAD}

\title{my report title}
\author{my name}
\date{my date}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

In fact, I am trying to create a document in APA style. Everything is fine now, but the problem is that I need the running head be on my title page as well. In addition, current title page number is shown below the page while based on the APA style I should put it on top of the page on the right corner in the header.

I was wondering how I can start applying the `fancyhdr` from the title page. OR is there any way to customize the first page with the current settings that I have?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I have understood you would like a running head on your title page. You can do it by adding a `fancypagestyle` as in example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Footer line not visible with 0pt
  \lhead{MY RUNNING HEAD}
}

\title{my report title}
\author{my name}
\date{my date}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\subsection{Some section}
And here some text
\end{document}
```

If you also want a running head on the following pages you could just create another `fancypagestyle`, and call it with `\pagestyle{myotherstyle}` after `\newpage`, for example

```
% Define another page style
\fancypagestyle{myotherstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Footer line not visible with 0pt
  \lhead{MY OTHER RUNNING HEAD}
}
```

Comment: Are you able to compile my document with original settings with your part added? It seems that it is not compilable.

Comment: By a slightly modified version I figured what I should do! Thx!

Comment: You should probably mention that the titlepage does not use `plain` style in case of having the `titlepage` document class option, it's `empty` style then. And `\clearpage` should be applied before a new pagestyle is used