# Hitec change amount of content in the header

Tags: document-classes

I've been trying out the Hitec class package to produce technical documents. The documentation is very sparse, however. Available here:

https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hitec/hitec_doc.pdf

I cannot figure out how to have 3 elements in the page header like they do. Any ideas?

Here's a mwe: (taken from [What are the available "documentclass" types and their uses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses/99707#99707))

```
\documentclass{hitec}
\author{by Fran}
\title{A Minimal Working Example}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header consists of the author name on the left, the company name on the right and the “confidential” marker in the middle.

```
\documentclass{hitec}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{Wile E. Coyote}
\title{A Minimal Working Example}

\company{ACME}

\confidential{Don't show to Road Runners}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use package `fancyhdr`. See its manual for more options.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{hitec}
\author{by Fran}
\title{A Minimal Working Example}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\usepackage{graphicx}% not needed

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[R]{The Company, Ltd}
\fancyhead[L]{Fran san}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{- Unlimited Distribution -}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I got close to this using fancyhead, but if you take a closer look, the top bar no longer goes accross the whole page like it did before (or like it does in the document link I sent), and the footer to my knowledge has the same issue. Is there a way in the fancyhead package to fix that, I haven't found a way to force it past the paragraph width so far.

Comment: That can happen when using old classes like hitec. // Did you glance through all 80 pages of the fancyhdr manual? // A way moving forward is. e.g. searching here for tag [fancyhdr] https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fancyhdr and narrow down the search. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364345/starting-fancyhdr-from-title-pagefrom this process via search https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfancyhdr%5D+title+page.